# PostgreSQL: "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to remove all events from event templates that are included in request groups of 1 or 3, depending on the type of the latter.

The request fields and the templates included in them are connected in pairs (request 'id' field - template 'from' field). As well as pairs template - events (the 'id' field of the template - the 'tmpid' field of the event).

[For clarity, I will attach a screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw8kc.jpg)

I need to remove all events from all templates related to obsolete requests (there may be several of them).

I tried to do like this:

```
DELETE FROM
    public.events_tmp_acc
WHERE "tmpid" IN (
        SELECT "id"
        FROM public.tmp_acc
        WHERE "from" IN (
                SELECT "id" 
                FROM
                    public.events_req_form 
                WHERE
                    to_date("date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_date( (
                            SELECT
                                "date"
                            FROM
                                public.events_req_form
                            WHERE
                                "isActive" = true
                        ),
                        'YYYY-MM-DD'
                    )
                    AND "isAccepted" = true
            )
    );
```

But I ran into an error: "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".
Where is my problem?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why is the column `date` not defined with the data type `date`?  That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: The `< to_date( ( <subquery>` seems to return more than 1 row. What do you want to do here?

Comment: Using the to_date method, I am converting the 'date' value to the 'date' type. There I want to get a number of requests that are already outdated. Events from each stale request should be removed.

Comment: "*I am converting the 'date' value to the 'date' type.*" - if you are storing date values, then the column should be defined with the data type `date`. Storing dates in `varchar` columns is a huge mistake. But that is unrelated to your error message, it's just really bad database design.

Comment: @jarlh I converted the 'date' field format to the appropriate type. Apparently, this is not the problem, because the same error takes off.

SELECT with the "isActive" flag is guaranteed to return one field, since there is always one active event.

Comment: One _column_, but the problem is the number of rows. Which of the dates returned do you want to use in the comparison?

Comment: @jarlh I need to use everything. I need to remove all events of all templates that are related to stale requests.

Comment: All dates `SELECT "date" FROM public.events_req_form WHERE                                "isActive" = true` returns?

Comment: In the case of returning one date - the date of the active request. All requests whose date is before the active date must be returned upstream to get their id.

Answer (score 0):

The `"isActive"` subquery might return multiple rows. One possible way to fix that would be to use IN here too or use the EXISTS clause, like (for the part after "from" IN):

```
SELECT outdated."id" 
FROM   public.events_req_form outdated
WHERE  outdated."isAccepted" = true
AND    EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM public.events_req_form active
  WHERE  active."isActive" = true
  AND    to_date(active."date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') > to_date(outdated."date", 'YYYY.MM.DD')
)
```

Comment: The solution helped! It turned out that the problem was maintaining consistency.
We can have several requests for one date in our list of requests, but only one can be approved per day. It was worth setting a limit and everything worked.

It is worth considering that additional control over this condition is required from the backend. Thanks a lot.